# Big Query "WITH statement" causing syntax error "WITH trips AS ( --invalid syntax)

Tags: python, sql, common-table-expression, google-cloud-datalab

My question is about Trying this in Google Data lab, but keeps returning a syntax error

```
  File "<ipython-input-26-03f6ca240d16>", line 4
    WITH trips AS (
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

```
import google.datalab.bigquery as bq
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import shutil

%bq query -n taxiquery
WITH trips AS (
  SELECT EXTRACT (DAYOFYEAR from pickup_datetime) AS daynumber 
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york.tlc_yellow_trips_*`
  where _TABLE_SUFFIX = @YEAR
)
SELECT daynumber, COUNT(1) AS numtrips FROM trips
GROUP BY daynumber ORDER BY daynumber

query_parameters = [
  {
    'name': 'YEAR',
    'parameterType': {'type': 'STRING'},
    'parameterValue': {'value': 2015}
  }
]
trips = taxiquery.execute(query_params=query_parameters).result().to_dataframe()
trips[:5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the query definition out into its own cell. The `%bq query...` is a multiline magic syntax that needs to be in a cell on its own.